# export to JSON/XML drawing data from google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, export

Hi I am using this drawing extended library for google maps API.[Link Here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools)

The drawing functionality is working fine, but now I need to save all the drawing objects created on the Map. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle drawing events. Information about drawn object is passesed to a callback function i.e.:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE) {
        var radius = event.overlay.getRadius();
    }
});
```